# Copying one image onto another with PIL

Tags: python, graphics, png, python-imaging-library

I have an image file of a small dimension (300x300), and I want to "paste" this entire image onto a certain place on a larger image which I create with PIL (2400x1700). Here's my code:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.new("RGB", (2400, 1700), "white")

im2 = Image.open("smallimage.jpg")

im.paste(im2, (20,20,300,300))

im.save("test.png")
```

The error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "chart.py", line 6, in <module>
    im.paste(im2, (20,20,300,300))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1351, in paste
    self.im.paste(im, box)
ValueError: images do not match
```

Is there a way which I can paste/copy the smaller image onto the larger one, without doing any transformations to the smaller image (such as cropping)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second argument in the paste method `(20,20,300,300)` is wrong:

- Your first image is 300x300.
- The paste method take in second argument either a 2-tuple giving the 
  upper left corner a 4-tuple defining the left, upper, right, and
  lower pixel coordinate

With `(20,20,300,300)` you say that your image is 280x280.

The following code should do it, for the 4-tuple:

```
im.paste(im2, (20,20,320,320))
```

For the the 2-tuple:

```
im.paste(im2, (20,20))
```

Comment: Why even have the first option then?